# SQL Server 2014 database permissions

Tags: sql-server

I installed SQL Server 2014 in the default location, but I want to create a database in a different location. It's telling me I have no access. The server I am using is my local machine, which has administrator permissions. When I go into the server properties and change the default mdf/ldf locations and hit OK, it goes back to its default location. Nothing I've found online is helping. I am at my wits end, been trying for hours now.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx

Comment: Or are you saying you are getting a permissions error? That is likely because the user account that sql server is using does not have permission to write to the new file location. If in doubt (especially since it just a local instance) change the permissions on the folder to allow the sql user permission to write to that folder.

Comment: I am getting a permission error. I went into the security tab of the folder, and it seems as the server that sql is running on (as well as all other users) have full control of the directory. Is there anything else I should be doing there?

Comment: Only as a test to see if it is permission related, give that folder Everyone and Full Access. If it still doesn't work then it is the wrong folder or some other issue.

Comment: That seemed to work, I shared the folder with everyone read/write. Now I need to figure out who exactly is supposed to be getting permission. Thank you. (How do I mark this as answered?)

Comment: Read this to see how to reply to people:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work